# Why does my JavaScript switch statement not work?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, switch-statement

I am trying to make a website that makes a Mario Kart Wii license. For some reason the switch statement always shows a picture of Baby Mario even if I select a different character. This is a work-in-progress project, which is why it does not look done. Here's my code:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 
 var canvas = document.getElementById("mainCanvas");
 var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
 
 var name = document.getElementById("name");
 var favRace = document.getElementById("favRace");
 var bgrnd = document.getElementById("bgrnd");
 var favChar = document.getElementById("favChar");
 
 switch (favChar.value) {
  case "Yoshi":
   img = document.getElementById("yoshi");
   break;
  case "Baby Luigi":
   img = document.getElementById("baby_luigi");
   break;
  case "Baby Daisy":
   img = document.getElementById("baby_daisy");
   break;
  case "Baby Peach":
   img = document.getElementById("baby_peach");
   break;
  case "Baby Mario":
   img = document.getElementById("baby_mario");
   break;
  default:
   img = "NULL";
 }
 
 $("#create").click(function(){
  drawText("Name: " + name.value, 75, 10);
  drawText("Favorite Race: " + favRace.value, 75, 20);
  drawImg(img, 0, 0, 62, 72);
  canvas.style.background = bgrnd.value;
  document.getElementById("mainCanvas").style.display = "block";
 });

 function drawRect(x, y) {
  ctx.fillStyle = "green";
  ctx.fillRect(x, y, 8, 5);
 }

 function drawText(text, x, y) {
  ctx.fillStyle = "black";
  ctx.font = "9px Arial";
  ctx.fillText(text, x, y);
 }
 
 function drawImg(img, x, y, width, height) {
  ctx.drawImage(img, x, y, width, height);
  ctx.strokeRect(x, y, width + 4, height + 4);
  ctx.strokeStyle = "black";
  ctx.lineWidth = 2;
 }

});
```

```css
@font-face {
 font-family: Bandits;
 src: url("Bandits.ttf");
 font-weight: bold;
}

#mainCanvas {
 height: 300px;
 width: 530px;
 border: 2px solid black;
 display: none;
}

.img {
 display: none;
}

header {
 background: -linear-gradient(#EEEEEE, #DDDDDD);
 background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#EEEEEE, #DDDDDD);
 height: 50px;
 margin: -.6%;
 padding: 10px;
}

#title {
 font-family: Bandits;
 font-size: 55px;
 color: #585858;
}

body {
 background-color: rgb(134, 170, 230);
}

fieldset {
 width: 60%;
 text-align: left;
}

.yellow {
 color: yellow;
}

#license {
 border: 2px solid black;
 border-radius: 5px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<HTML lang = "en">
 <head>
  <meta charset = "UTF-8">
  <meta name = "description" content = "Create Mario Kart Wii Licenses!">
  <meta name = "author" content = "Adam Oates">
  <meta name = "title" content = "Mario Kart Wii">
  <title title = "Mario Kart Wii | License Maker">
   Mario Kart Wii | License Maker
  </title>
  <link rel = "apple-touch-icon" href = "">
  <link rel = "shortcut icon" href = "">
  <link rel = "stylesheet" type = "text/css" href = "main.css">
  <script type = "text/javascript" src = "http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.js"></script>
  <script type = "text/javascript" src = "main.js"></script>
 </head>
 <body>
  <header>
   <div id = "title">
    MKWii License Maker
   </div>
  </header><br><br><br><br>
  
  <section>
   <div align = "center">
    <form action = "" method = "post">
     <fieldset>
      Name: <input type = "text" id = "name" placeholder = "Name"><br><br>
      Favorite Race: <input type = "text" id = "favRace" placeholder = "Favorite Race"><br><br>
      Overall Ranking: <select id = "ranking">
       <option id = "e" value = "e">E</option>
       <option id = "d" value = "d">D</option>
       <option id = "c" value = "c">C</option>
       <option id = "b" value = "b">B</option>
       <option id = "a" value = "a">A</option>
       <option id = "star1" value = "star1">&#9733;</option>
       <option id = "star2" value = "star2">&#9733;&#9733;</option>
       <option id = "star3" value = "star3">&#9733;&#9733;&#9733;</option>
      </select><br><br>
      Versus Points: <select id = "vrPoints">
       <option id = "1000+" value = "1000+">1000+</option>
       <option id = "2000+" value = "2000+">2000+</option>
       <option id = "3000+" value = "3000+">3000+</option>
       <option id = "4000+" value = "4000+">4000+</option>
       <option id = "5000+" value = "5000+">5000+</option>
       <option id = "6000+" value = "6000+">6000+</option>
       <option id = "7000+" value = "7000+">7000+</option>
       <option id = "8000+" value = "8000+">8000+</option>
       <option id = "9000+" value = "9000+">9000+</option>
      </select><br><br>
      Favorite Character: <select id = "favChar">
       <option value = "Baby Mario" id = "bm">Baby Mario</option>
       <option value = "Baby Luigi" id = "bl">Baby Luigi</option>
       <option value = "Baby Peach" id = "bp">Baby Peach</option>
       <option value = "Baby Daisy" id = "bd">Baby Daisy</option>
       <option value = "Toad" id = "toad">Toad</option>
       <option value = "Toadette" id = "tdet">Toadette</option>
       <option value = "Koopa Troopa" id = "kt">Koopa Troopa</option>
       <option value = "Dry Bones" id = "db">Dry Bones</option>
       <option value = "Mario" id = "mro">Mario</option>
       <option value = "Luigi" id = "lgi">Luigi</option>
       <option value = "Peach" id = "pch">Peach</option>
       <option value = "Daisy" id = "dsy">Daisy</option>
       <option value = "Yoshi" id = "ysh">Yoshi</option>
       <option value = "Birdo" id = "bdo">Birdo</option>
       <option value = "Diddy Kong" id = "diddy">Diddy Kong</option>
       <option value = "Bowser Jr." id = "jr">Bowser Jr.</option>
       <option value = "Wario" id = "wro">Wario</option>
       <option value = "Waluigi" id = "wlgi">Waluigi</option>
       <option value = "Donkey Kong" id = "dk">Donkey Kong</option>
       <option value = "Bowser" id = "bwr">Bowser</option>
       <option value = "King Boo" id = "kboo">King Boo</option>
       <option value = "Rosalina" id = "rlna">Rosalina</option>
       <option value = "Funkey Kong" id = "fk">Funkey Kong</option>
       <option value = "Dry Bowser" id = "drybwr">Dry Bowser</option>
      </select><br><br>
      Secondary Character: <select id = "secChar">
       <option value = "Baby Mario" id = "bm">Baby Mario</option>
       <option value = "Baby Luigi" id = "bl">Baby Luigi</option>
       <option value = "Baby Peach" id = "bp">Baby Peach</option>
       <option value = "Baby Daisy" id = "bd">Baby Daisy</option>
       <option value = "Toad" id = "toad">Toad</option>
       <option value = "Toadette" id = "tdet">Toadette</option>
       <option value = "Koopa Troopa" id = "kt">Koopa Troopa</option>
       <option value = "Dry Bones" id = "db">Dry Bones</option>
       <option value = "Mario" id = "mro">Mario</option>
       <option value = "Luigi" id = "lgi">Luigi</option>
       <option value = "Peach" id = "pch">Peach</option>
       <option value = "Daisy" id = "dsy">Daisy</option>
       <option value = "Yoshi" id = "ysh">Yoshi</option>
       <option value = "Birdo" id = "bdo">Birdo</option>
       <option value = "Diddy Kong" id = "diddy">Diddy Kong</option>
       <option value = "Bowser Jr." id = "jr">Bowser Jr.</option>
       <option value = "Wario" id = "wro">Wario</option>
       <option value = "Waluigi" id = "wlgi">Waluigi</option>
       <option value = "Donkey Kong" id = "dk">Donkey Kong</option>
       <option value = "Bowser" id = "bwr">Bowser</option>
       <option value = "King Boo" id = "kboo">King Boo</option>
       <option value = "Rosalina" id = "rlna">Rosalina</option>
       <option value = "Funkey Kong" id = "fk">Funkey Kong</option>
       <option value = "Dry Bowser" id = "drybwr">Dry Bowser</option>
      </select><br><br>
      Vehichle Used For Favorite Character: <select id = "favKart">
       <optgroup label = "Light Weight">
       <option value = "Standard Kart S" id = "sks">Standard Kart S</option>
       <option value = "Booster Seat" id = "bseat">Booster Seat</option>
       <option value = "Mini Beast" id = "mb">Mini Beast</option>
       <option value = "Cheap Charger" id = "cc">Cheap Charger</option>
       <option value = "Tiny Titan" id = "tt">Tiny Titan</option>
       <option value = "Blue Falcon" id = "bf">Blue Falcon</option>
       <option value = "Standard Bike S" id = "sbs">Standard Bike S</option>
       <option value = "Bullet Bike" id = "bb">Bullet Bike</option>
       <option value = "Bit Bike" id = "bitb">Bit Bike</option>
       <option value = "Quacker" id = "qkr">Quacker</option>
       <option value = "Magikruser" id = "mgcCrsr">Magikruser</option>
       <option value = "Jet Bubble" id = "jb">Jet Bubble</option>
       <optgroup label = "Medium Weight">
       <option value = "Standard Kart M" id = "skm">Standard Kart M</option>
       <option value = "Classic Dragster" id = "cd">Classic Dragster</option>
       <option value = "Wild Wing" id = "ww">Wild Wing</option>
       <option value = "Super Blooper" id = "sb">Super Blooper</option>
       <option value = "Daytripper" id = "dtrp">Daytripper</option>
       <option value = "Sprinter" id = "sprnt">Sprinter</option>
       <option value = "Standard Bike M" id = "sbm">Standard Bike M</option>
       <option value = "Mach Bike" id = "machb">Mach Bike</option>
       <option value = "Sugarscoot" id = "sugar">Sugarscoot</option>
       <option value = "Zip Zip" id = "zip">Zip Zip</option>
       <option value = "Sneakster" id = "sneak">Sneakster</option>
       <option value = "Dolphin Dasher" id = "dphin">Dolphin Dasher</option>
       <optgroup label = "Heavy Weight">
       <option value = "Standard Kart L" id = "skl">Standard Kart L</option>
       <option value = "Offroader" id = "offrdr">Offroader</option>
       <option value = "Flame Flyer" id = "ffly">Flame Flyer</option>
       <option value = "Pirahna Prowler" id = "prwlr">Pirahna Prowler</option>
       <option value = "Jetsetter" id = "jetstr">Jetsetter</option>
       <option value = "Honeycoupe" id = "hnycp">Honeycoupe</option>
       <option value = "Standard Bike L" id = "sbl">Standard Bike L</option>
       <option value = "Flame Runner" id = "frner">Flame Runner</option>
       <option value = "Wario Bike" id = "wrobike">Wario Bike</option>
       <option value = "Shooting Star" id = "shstr">Shooting Star</option>
       <option value = "Spear" id = "spear">Spear</option>
       <option value = "Phantom" id = "phntm">Phantom</option>
      </select><br><br>
      Vehichle Used For Secondary Character: <select id = "favKart">
       <optgroup label = "Light Weight">
       <option value = "Standard Kart S" id = "sks">Standard Kart S</option>
       <option value = "Booster Seat" id = "bseat">Booster Seat</option>
       <option value = "Mini Beast" id = "mb">Mini Beast</option>
       <option value = "Cheap Charger" id = "cc">Cheap Charger</option>
       <option value = "Tiny Titan" id = "tt">Tiny Titan</option>
       <option value = "Blue Falcon" id = "bf">Blue Falcon</option>
       <option value = "Standard Bike S" id = "sbs">Standard Bike S</option>
       <option value = "Bullet Bike" id = "bb">Bullet Bike</option>
       <option value = "Bit Bike" id = "bitb">Bit Bike</option>
       <option value = "Quacker" id = "qkr">Quacker</option>
       <option value = "Magikruser" id = "mgcCrsr">Magikruser</option>
       <option value = "Jet Bubble" id = "jb">Jet Bubble</option>
       <optgroup label = "Medium Weight">
       <option value = "Standard Kart M" id = "skm">Standard Kart M</option>
       <option value = "Classic Dragster" id = "cd">Classic Dragster</option>
       <option value = "Wild Wing" id = "ww">Wild Wing</option>
       <option value = "Super Blooper" id = "sb">Super Blooper</option>
       <option value = "Daytripper" id = "dtrp">Daytripper</option>
       <option value = "Sprinter" id = "sprnt">Sprinter</option>
       <option value = "Standard Bike M" id = "sbm">Standard Bike M</option>
       <option value = "Mach Bike" id = "machb">Mach Bike</option>
       <option value = "Sugarscoot" id = "sugar">Sugarscoot</option>
       <option value = "Zip Zip" id = "zip">Zip Zip</option>
       <option value = "Sneakster" id = "sneak">Sneakster</option>
       <option value = "Dolphin Dasher" id = "dphin">Dolphin Dasher</option>
       <optgroup label = "Heavy Weight">
       <option value = "Standard Kart L" id = "skl">Standard Kart L</option>
       <option value = "Offroader" id = "offrdr">Offroader</option>
       <option value = "Flame Flyer" id = "ffly">Flame Flyer</option>
       <option value = "Pirahna Prowler" id = "prwlr">Pirahna Prowler</option>
       <option value = "Jetsetter" id = "jetstr">Jetsetter</option>
       <option value = "Honeycoupe" id = "hnycp">Honeycoupe</option>
       <option value = "Standard Bike L" id = "sbl">Standard Bike L</option>
       <option value = "Flame Runner" id = "frner">Flame Runner</option>
       <option value = "Wario Bike" id = "wrobike">Wario Bike</option>
       <option value = "Shooting Star" id = "shstr">Shooting Star</option>
       <option value = "Spear" id = "spear">Spear</option>
       <option value = "Phantom" id = "phntm">Phantom</option>
      </select><br><br>
      License Color: <select id = "bgrnd">
       <option value = "blue" id = "blue">Blue</option>
       <option value = "red" id = "red">Red</option>
       <option value = "white" id = "white">White</option>
       <option value = "green" id = "green">Green</option>
       <option value = "navy" id = "navy">Navy Blue</option>
      </select><br><br>
      <input type = "button" id = "create" value = "Create License">
     </fieldset>
    </form><br><br><br>
    <canvas id = "mainCanvas"></canvas>
   </div>
   <img src = "images/yoshi.png" id = "yoshi" class = "img">
   <img src = "images/baby_mario.png" id = "baby_mario" class = "img">
   <img src = "images/baby_luigi.png" id = "baby_luigi" class = "img">
   <img src = "images/baby_daisy.png" id = "baby_daisy" class = "img">
   <img src = "images/baby_peach.png" id = "baby_peach" class = "img">
  </section>
  
  <footer>
   
  </footer>
 </body>
</HTML>
```

Comment: The only switch statement shown in your code only runs when the document is initially loaded so thus it can never have any value other than what is originally coded into the HTML of the page.

Comment: You're switch statement works fine, as soon as the document is ready, which is the only time it is ever executed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to wrap it into event handler, and to get the selected value, like this:

```
$('#favChar').change(function(){
   var favChar = document.getElementById("favChar");

  var favorite = favChar.options[favChar.selectedIndex].value;

    switch (favorite) {
        case "Yoshi":
            img = document.getElementById("yoshi");
            break;
        case "Baby Luigi":
            img = document.getElementById("baby_luigi");
            break;
        case "Baby Daisy":
            img = document.getElementById("baby_daisy");
            break;
        case "Baby Peach":
            img = document.getElementById("baby_peach");
            break;
        case "Baby Mario":
            img = document.getElementById("baby_mario");
            break;
        default:
            img = "NULL";
    }


 });
```

[Show log](http://jsbin.com/xesahe/edit?js,console,output)